# How to set up Micro CloudFoundry on Windows

Tags: cloud-foundry

tldr; This question was to get help setting up Micro Cloud Foundry on Windows XP behind a corporate firewall as an innovation-demonstration project for a Fortune 500 IT departent. Basically, the project stalled, despite this stackoverflow page - the magic wasn't strong enough. I am accepting @DanHigman answer below, but if anyone sees this and can provide a simple straight-forward answer, by all means...

---

Can anyone provide a clear step-by-step on setting up MCF on a Windows (XP in my case) machine behind a corporate firewall, for demostrating the feasibility of PaaS in the corporate IT world?

My VM is installed and running and I can use the menu ok. I have vmc working. I have a test Node.js server app, that works on local, ready to push. But I can't get past that stage.

The firewall gave me trouble so I lowered my goal to just work offline. I followed the instructions noted below as best I could, but often the instructions are mac oriented - I would like them for a Windows command line (especially SSH tunneling):

http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2011/09/08/working-offline-with-micro-cloud-foundry/

http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/20332921-micro-cloud-foundry-trouble-shooting-help

This blogger may have half-way covered my problem doing the SSH tunnel settings, but all it gives is "use Putty" - more detail would help:

http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/20419943-using-micro-cloud-locally

Also, whenever the vmc obviously gets an error or other message, it only outputs the following in the command line:

```
vmc target http://api.vcap.me

<<<
[200, "<html><body>SNP/2.0/102/Unknown Command 'info'</body></html>\r\n\r\n", {}
]
>>>
```

Thanks for any help. BTW - I know I could do this on my mac, the big obstacle is the windows and firewall environment.

Update:

@Dan and @ebottard: Thanks to your help, I'm almost there. ping is working now, hosts file seems right, but the vmc target api.vcap.me still does not find the VM at that `192.168.253.128` IP - even tho ping does. In the first link above, Martin wrote the following, but assuming we are doing it on a mac:

> After the update is complete, you will need to make some changes on your local system. What you will need to do is to set up an SSH tunnel to access your Micro Cloud Foundry VM (note that you will need to supply the IP address in the command below with the actual IP of your VM, which is displayed in the console).

```
sudo ssh -L 80:192.168.168.149:80 vcap@192.168.168.149
Password:
vcap@192.168.168.149's password:Â
```

> The first password being prompted is the sudo password for your machine, as it is needed to open port 80 which requires root privileges. The second password is the vcap user password which you entered during the initial configuration of your Micro Cloud Foundry.

I need to have these instructions translated into Windows,  and all I have to go on is that I might use puTTy (which I have downloaded) to do it. Any more ideas?

Comment: My guess would be that api.vcap.me gets resolved to one of your corporate machines (hence the SNP/xx stuff which, unless I'm not mistaken, has nothing to do with cloud foundry). Can you `ping api.vcap.me` and compare with the IP of your VM?

Comment: The ping to api.vcap.me showed `127.0.0.1` - the VM Current Configuration shows IP Address: `192.168.253.128`. I assume I have to change a setting on my network connections - just not sure exactly how.  I am seeing a LAN connector called VMware Network Adapter VMnet1 (also another called VMNet8 - dupe?) and have set the DNS on them to the `192.168.253.128` IP, leaving the actual IP to be set automatically.

Comment: After adding a line to hosts file I now get the IP of the VM from pinging api.vcap.me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're running an application on your Windows machine called "Snarl" (a poor Windows-based clone of the OS 10 app Growl :-p). It looks like it's interfering with communication to the MCF intstance, close it and have another try.

Comment: That worked - I had to Quit from Snarl, which I found in my tray, then I started getting real messages:      >vmc target api.vcap.me
    Host is not available or is not valid: 'http://api.vcap.me'
    Would you like see the response? [yN]: y
    HTTP exception: Errno::ECONNREFUSED:No connection could be made because the targ
    et machine actively refused it. - connect(2)

Comment: Yup, vcap.me resolves to the loopback adapter. If you are using VMWare Player you should be able to local requests to port 80 via NAT to the VM using a tool called vmnetcfg. Alternatively you could create hostname entries on your machine for api.vcap.me and any app you deploy to point to the VM, but this is a pain in the long run.

Comment: Fascinating stuff - more like a cat-and-mouse game to get the vmnetcfg tool. All top searches pointed to using this: `VMware-player-5.0.1-894247.exe /e .\extract` but that did not yield a `network.cab` to look in. I also had to originally download the VMWare VIX package to use MCF - but no clue if they have moved it there or anywhere else (in)conveniently located in my free download... I will try the hosts file approach. Thanks.

Comment: Eugh, I use Fusion and its a simple case of just editing a settings file and it works, but then again, it's not a free product!

Comment: OK - added the entry `127.0.0.1       vcap.me api.vcap.me` to my hosts file - restarted everything - same result as already reported.  @Dan - this help got me significantly closer.

Comment: The entry in your hosts file (on the host, in Windows) needs to point to the address of the virtual machine (running in VMWare player), not 127.0.0.1

Comment: That change was made (see main comments above) - still no joy.